# Isomorphism of a polynomial ring $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Show that the map $\phi:F[x]\to F[x]$ given by $\phi(f(x))=f(x+1)$ is an isomorphism such that $\phi(a)=a$ for every $a\in F$.

So far I have that $\phi$ is a homomorphism because, Let $f,g\in F[x]$ then

$\phi(f(x)+g(x))=(f+g)(x+1)=f(x+1)+g(x+1)=\phi(f(x))+\phi(g(x))$.

$\phi(f(x))\phi(g(x))=f(x+1)g(x+1)=(fg)(x+1)=\phi(f(x)g(x))$.

However I'm having trouble showing this is an isomorphic. Here's my attempt,

$\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x))$ then $f(x+1)=g(x+1)$ then $x+1=x+1$ since f and g isomorphic then $x=x$. Therefore injective.

I'm not sure how to show it is surjective.

Comment: Hint: It's actually a simpler task to give an explicit inverse map for $\phi$.

Comment: Showing it's surjective isn't that difficult, although it feels the same as constructing the inverse.  Just think --- what does $\phi(f(x-1))$ look like?

Comment: @Mark Why is it $\phi(f(x-1))$ not $\phi(f(x+1))$?

Comment: $\phi$ isn't the inverse.  I meant if you want to show it's surjective, you say that $f(x)\in F[x]$ (meaning the codomain), then as $\phi(f(x-1)) = f(x)$, you've found an element that maps to it.

Comment: @Mark Okay I think see that you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The inverse map sends $g(x)$ to $g(x-1)$

Comment: To show that it is  surjective?

Comment: If you can show that there exists an inverse map to it you have effectively shown that it is invertible and thus bijective.

Comment: @StillLearning There are two ways to show isomorphic: Either "Structure preserving" + "Injective and Surjective", or "Structure Preserving" + "Structure Preserving Inverse", they're suggesting you do the second

Comment: @thedilated So now I am trying to do this both ways. So you are saying that $\phi^{-1}(f(x))=f(x-1)$ since $\phi^{-1}(\phi(f(x))=\phi^{-1}(f(x+1))=f(x)$?

Comment: @thedilated: More than "effectively"; the general definition of "isomorphism" is "a homomorphism that has an inverse homomorphism", so showing there exists an inverse ***is*** showing it is invertible. It's only in odd special cases (like groups or rings) that bijective homomorphisms happen to be isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

As thedilated shows in his answer: you can just construct an inverse map to show something is a bijection (as Ben P. says in the comments, this is a pretty easy way to show bijectivity for this problem).

I will approach the problem from the way that you were trying to do it (i.e. show injectivity and surjectivity of $\phi$).

Injectivity: suppose $\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x))$. Then we have $f(x+1)=g(x+1)$, and thus $f((x-1)+1)=g((x-1)+1)\implies f(x)=g(x)$.

Surjectivity: take $f(x)\in F[x]$. Then $\phi (f(x-1))=f(x)$.

Now, clearly if $f_a(x)=a$ for each $x$ then $\phi(a)=\phi (f_a(x))=f_a(x+1)=a$.

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have asked this earlier but why is the condition that $\phi(a)=a$ is needed?

Comment: There's certain results that use the property $\phi (a)=a$, so maybe you establish this for setup for other problems. For instance, if we have such an isomorphism $\phi:F[x]\to F[x]$ with the property $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in F$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $\phi (f(x))$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. That is part b of the problem which don't have to go over.